# Is there a program to upload an image directly from the Windows context menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu, upload

Here is the deal, I want to make right click on a image file on my PC and in the context menu hit an option who say: "Upload to Imageshack" or similar, do you know a program who do this?

Comment: Do you mean it is already saved on your hard drive, or from the internet? i.e. Internet -> ImageShack or PC -> ImageShack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Rightload](http://rightload.org/) or [TinyPicUploader](http://eden.fm/tinypic-uploader/)

`<shameless self plug>`

Not quite what you need but if you need to take a snapshot of a section of your screen or a full screen and upload it to imgur here's something which I had written( [sources](http://j.mp/ateaF5) / [direct download](http://j.mp/cFESGw)).

`</shameless self plug>`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use dropbox which offers 2 gigs free. If you put the file in the 'Public' folder you can right click on the file and goto the Dropbox option then Copy Public Url. This is what I use when I want to share a picture quickly.